# Use php variables in multiple css files

Tags: php, css, variables, include

I know I can ask my php file to act like a css one, I already did. My problem is how to use variables in another css-php files ? My css.php file with global variables is loaded before others in html list, but it doesn't seem it includes it.

My html :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/variables.css.php">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/main.css.php">
```

My variables.css.php file :

```
 <?php
   header("Content-type: text/css");
   $color = "#004D7F";
 ?>
```

My main.css.php file :

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css");  ?>
body {
    background: <?=$color;?>;
}
```

But it doesn't work, it doesn't recognize the variable $color. So I tried to add at main.css.php :

```
require("/assets/css/variables.css.php");
```

But it threw an error. Does someone know the answer ? How to get access php variables in another php file acting as css ?

Thank you in advance !

-- Carlos

Comment: Can you give us the error generated by the `require` ? please

Comment: I can't, because it works as a css file

Comment: Just few more questions. How did you launch the .html file ? Do you use apache (for example localhost/test.html) or directly launch the by double clicking on the file ? If you launch by double clicking, it can't work because your .php files can't be executed.

Comment: When i said apache i mean your local webserver sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the web server sees is not what the browser sees. Specifically, while the path to the file would be `http://domain/assets/css/variables.css.php`, on the server side you need to reflect the location the actual code. With the leading forward slash, the server is looking for the file starting with the root of the filesystem.

> Remove the leading slash

That may be enough to make it work if the relative path is correct

If that doesn't help,

> Remove parts of the path until it works

If both files are sitting in `/var/www/html/assets/css/`, then just doing `require("variables.css.php")` is enough.

---

Additionally, there's no need to include the `variables.css.php` inside the webpage. PHP will populate the values automatically inside `main.css.php`.

Comment: Thank you, you were right. I finaly just wrote require("variables.css.php") and remove the include in the html page and it works.